# Uncaught AggregateError in Deno pooled map server

Tags: typescript, deno

I have this TypeScript code

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.203.0/http/server.ts"
import { pooledMap } from "https://deno.land/std@0.173.0/async/pool.ts"


const server = serve({ port: 3000 })

async function handleRequest(request: Request) {
    var res: Response = new Response("Hello, World!")
    return res
}

const ress = pooledMap(
    window.navigator.hardwareConcurrency - 1,
    server,
    req => handleRequest(req)
)

for await (const res of ress) {
    res.send()
}
```

and I got this error:

> error: Uncaught AggregateError: Threw while mapping.
> new AggregateError(errors, ERROR_WHILE_MAPPING_MESSAGE),
> ^
> at https://deno.land/std@0.173.0/async/pool.ts:90:9

so what is the issue, the error is not telling me anything besides that is caused by multiple errors

Comment: [Type-checking](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/advanced/typescript/overview) (`deno check module.ts`) and [linting](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/tools/linter) (`deno lint module.ts`) are great first steps to take that can help you understand a number of errors in that module file.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error being swallowed is

```
TypeError: array is not async iterable
```

You're passing `server` whichs is a `Promise` when `pooledMap` expects `Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>`.

---

In any case `serve` is deprecated: https://deno.land/std@0.203.0/http/server.ts?s=serve

> Deprecated (will be removed after 1.0.0) Use Deno.serve instead.